# How to find multiple shortest path using Memgraph and MAGE?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-databases, memgraphdb

How can I find multiple shortest path using Memgraph and MAGE? I'm looking for a solution that would use Yen's, Dijkstra's or Star algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Memgraph has some built-in algorithms that help you find all shortest paths.
For example, to obtain all shortest paths, you need to call `[*ALLSHORTEST (r, n | r.weight)]` where `r`  and `n`  define the current expansion relationship and node.

The following is a weighted query based on the weight property on each visited relationship:

```
MATCH path=(n {id: 0})-[:Type *ALLSHORTEST (r, n | r.weight)]-(m {id: 5})
RETURN path;
```

A more detailed explanation can be found at https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/reference-guide/built-in-graph-algorithms